# Get the same name of a csv file as the name of my pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with several `csv` file and also compressed file in `gz` format type. Each of these unzipped `gz` file also contain one `csv` file. I want to extract all of them and create a dataframe for each one with same name as the `csv` file name (without the extension).

For example, if have the following files:

```
train.csv
test.csv
validation.csv.gz
```

I want to have 3 dataframes objects whose names are exactly : train, test and validation.

I've tried this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip

extension = ".gz"

for item in os.listdir():
    if item.endswith(extension):
        with gzip.open(item) as f:
            item.split('.', 1)[0] = pd.read_csv(f) #Split on the first occurence of '.' and give this name to my dataframe
    else:
        item.split('.', 1)[0] = pd.read_csv(item)
```

This code doesn't work because when I try to access my environment variables, python couldn't find them.

Any help, please !!

Comment: Can you paste your error here

Comment: @user2510479, there is no error.

Comment: What environment variables are you trying to access, and where’s the code that attempts to do it?

Comment: Is python not able to find your files?

Comment: @abarnert, my code is supposed to create 3 dataframe object and I should have been able to acces them in my jupyter notebook just by printing their names (i.e. writing `train` in the below cell should give me the content of my `train.csv` file in a pandas dataframe format.

Comment: @user2510479, since I'm not seeing any error, I can say my files have been read succesfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. If you want to dynamically assign an object to a given string, just make use of [exec](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html).

> This statement supports dynamic execution of Python code. The first
>   expression should evaluate to either a string, an open file object, or
>   a code object.

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip

extension = ".gz"

for item in os.listdir():
    if item.endswith(extension):
        with gzip.open(item) as f:
            exec(item.split('.', 1)[0] + "=" + "pd.read_csv(f)" ) #Split on the first occurence of '.' and give this name to my dataframe
    else:
        exec(item.split('.', 1)[0] + "=" + "pd.read_csv('" + item + "')")
```

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré don't forget upvoting and ticking this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

While it's possible to name variables via strings, it is strongly discouraged. A dictionary is performant and allows you to maintain a collection of objects in a structured way.

```
d = {}

for item in os.listdir():
    fn, ext = item.split('.')
    if ext == 'gz':
        with gzip.open(item) as f:
            d[fn] = pd.read_csv(f)
    else:
        d[fn] = pd.read_csv(item)
```

Then access via `d['train']`, `d['test']`, etc.

Your code does not work because `item.split('.', 1)[0]` is a scalar, not a variable name to which you can assign an object.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, but your code still doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: `type(item.split('.', 1)[0])` gave me a `string`

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré, Yes, a string is a scalar, it's immutable. You should share the error you get with the above code.

Comment: the fact is there is no error. My jupyter cell execute the whole without showing me any problem.

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré, You'll have to do some debugging, e.g. print each line where you define a variable. I've also updated the code to simplify separating filename from extension.